# Keyboard Shortcut several Keys

Tags: keyboard

I would like to set up a system (or define a keyboard shortcut) so when you type the following

> sum

I have the following print at the current selection.

```
NotebookWrite[
 InputNotebook[],
 ToBoxes[Unevaluated@Sum[Placeholder[ ], {t, 1, n}]],
 Placeholder]
```

This only works partially works b/c it removes focus.

```
x = Input[""]
```

Comment: Unless you want to do it in Mathematica for you own specific reasons (portability maybe), I would strongly recommend [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)? The pain you have to go through for that simple task is not worth the effort in Mathematica. In Autohotkey, that task is a one-liner: `::sum::Sum[Placeholder[ ], \`{t, 1, n\`}]{Left 5}`

Comment: What would be the easiest way to run a M Function?  Or how might I Print a ToBoxes version?  Autohotkey doesn't seem to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thinking it through some more this is the best solution I have come up with so far 
is to run the following in Mathematica so you can paste code into Mathematica that has formatting

```
FrontEndExecute[
 FrontEnd`AddMenuCommands[
  "DuplicatePreviousOutput", {Delimiter, 
   MenuItem["Raw Paste Clipboard", FrontEnd`KernelExecute[

     NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], 
      Catch[NotebookGet@ClipboardNotebook[] /. 
        Cell[r_, ___] :> Block[{}, Throw[r, tag] /; True];
       $Failed, tag], Placeholder]

     ], MenuKey["v", Modifiers -> {"Control", "Shift"}], 
    System`MenuEvaluator -> Automatic]}]]
```

Next you can create Autohotkey scripts like the following

```
*SC023:: 
  clipboard = 
  (
    \!\(
    \*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 
    1\), \(\[Placeholder]\)]\[Placeholder]\)
  )
  Send, ^+v
  return
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
    nb = CreateDocument[{}, 
   InputAliases -> {"sum" -> 
      "\!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(\[Placeholder] = \
\[Placeholder]\), \(\[Placeholder]\)]\)\[Placeholder]"}];
```

After evaluation a new notebook opens. Type in this notebook: Esc+sum+Esc. Done. Have fun!

Comment: I have been reconsidering my original thought if it is really a good idea but you definitely deserve and up vote.

Comment: @Liam William The up-vote is no matter. The point is that there are lots of already existing hot keys. I use some of them and there are too many to memorize them all. You might want to check Menu/Help/DocumentationCenter/tutorial/EnteringTwoDimensionalInput. Otherwise if you open any panel, such as Menu/Palette/BasicMathAssistant or Menu/Palette/SpecialCharacters and hover the cursor over any button you will find the corresponding hot key below the palette. In particular, Esc+sum+Esc gives you the sum by itself without additional efforts. So it may be a good idea to check already existing keys

Comment: This should work pretty well if I combine it with an Autohotkey scriptw